# Make a custom row selectable in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have a custom listview with few elements added in, like `ImageView`, `TextView` and `View`. These three components make a single row and I want to make this whole `clickable`. What currently happening is when I put `android:background="@drawable/text_selection_file"` to `ImageView` or `TextView`, it selects the corresponding elements background only, not the whole line. As I have more than one rows so I can't put each row into a different `GroupView` for each in this way the property for every next row `android:layout_below="above_view"` doesn't work. So I need to find a way to do this trough which I can make selection of whole row. Currently it works over the particular selection of `TextView` or `ImageView` only but not both at a time. My code for `XML` is below

**CODE**

```
         //Above code for layout
         <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeLink"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_view"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/home" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/home_link"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_view"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Home"
            android:textColor="@color/WHITE"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/home_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/home_link"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/VIEW_COLOR" />
         //More rows down there
```

Comment: check if your imageview takes focus when you click on list row. if so add this to imageview `android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: ImageView and TextView takes focus individually when they are clicked!

Answer (score 0):

You can set onClickListener for row in ListView:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            //insert code
        }

    });
```

You can also wrap you row layout into compound view (e.g. like here http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html) and override setOnClickListener to interact with view's parts like this view (ImageButton with custom caption that allows to dynamically upload image to ImageButton and change Typeface of caption )

```
public class CaptionImageButton extends LinearLayout {
private ImageButton ibBackground;
private TextView tvCaption;


@Override
public void setOnClickListener(final View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    ibBackground.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}
```

}